# Число в двоичной системе счисления с лидирующими нулями

Tags: python, binary

Главное, чтобы было 1 байт — 8 цифр.

Например, функция `bin` переводит `1` в `0b1`, а требуется получить `0000 0001`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для неотрицательных целых чисел `n`:

```
bin(n)[2:].zfill(8)
```

---

Ответ из комментария [@BOPOH](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/5079/bopoh).

Answer (score 4):

`"{0:08b}".format(n)` например можно так.

Comment: get_bin = lambda x, n: x >= 0 and str(bin(x))[2:].zfill(n) or "-" + str(bin(x))[3:].zfill(n)

Comment: @НиколайМихальцов Это для меня слишком, я не настоящий питонист :-)

Comment: Спасибо !......

Comment: @НиколайМихальцов: первый нолик можно не использовать, если вам не надо поддерживать Python 2.6 (или старше). Ещё [`bin(n)[2:].zfill(8)`, (предложенный `@`BOPOH) который работает для неотрицательных чисел, может быть слегка быстрее чем `'{:08b}'.format(n)`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12161988/multiplying-a-huge-number-times-random-python/12162190#comment16278452_12162856). Хотя `.format()` мне кажется более читаемым здесь.

Answer (score 0):

В дополнение к ответу [Владимира Мартьянова](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/462253):

Начиная с Python 3.6 можно воспользоваться [F-строками](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) и возможностью использования знака подчёркивания `_` в качестве разделителя цифр числа:

```
f'{x:09_b}'
```

где `x` — это выражение, результат которого нужно вывести в двоичном представлении,
`:` отделяет это выражение от описания [форматирования](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) (язык то же, что и в методе `.format()`),
`0` задаёт символ заполнения,
`9` — это минимальное количество символов строке (8 на байт, один символ для разделителя),
`_` добавляет разделитель между каждыми четырьмя символами (наподобие разделителей тысяч в записи числа),
`b` указывает, что вывод должен производиться в двоичной системе счисления.

Например, при `x = 1` вывод будет почти таким, какой вам и требовался:

```
print(f'{1:09_b}')
# 0000_0001
```

Если подчёркивание в качестве разделителя не подходит, то можно легко заменить его на пробелы:

```
print(f'{1:09_b}'.replace('_', ' '))
# 0000 0001
```

Важно отметить, что при отрицательных значениях `x` этот код заберёт одну позицию на знак:

```
print(f'{-1:09_b}')
# -000_0001
```

Если всё же требуется обрабатывать и отрицательные числа, код можно дополнить одним условием:

```
x = -1
print(f'{x:0{9 if x > 0 else 10}_b}')
# -0000_0001
```

Также важно, что числа, не помещающиеся в выделенное пространство, не будут дополняться нулями слева, но разделение по 4 символа сохранится:

```
print(f'{8000:09_b}')
# 1_1111_0100_0000
```

Здесь играет роль то, что число `9` в форматирующем выражении описывает именно *минимальную* ширину строки, и никак не ограничивает её сверху.